# NFC geo location

Tags: geolocation, nfc

i have been asked by a customer to set up a page that collects an id that has been set in a url that has been pre programmed in to an NFC chip - the url that has been embedded is something like

http://www.mywebsite.co.uk?code=12345678

so i have a php page that collects that code and displays it on the screen, easy! They are now telling me they need the location of where the chip was scanned to be displayed too. so the question is does the lat and long have to be programmed in to the chip or does the android device send the lat and long along with the url?

or...

Do i just have to ask for the lat and long (using Javascript) when they arrive at the page?

Does any one know how this works?

Thanks in advance

Sam

Comment: Do the users have a specific NFC app which interacts with your server? Or do do you rely on the NFC mechanism prebuilt into the phone (NFC with URL starts the browser with that URL)?

Comment: The users are using the pre built reader in the device. I feel like it might be a case of either integrating a reader it in to their app I have built for them, or simply going down the HTML5 / JS route perhaps!

Comment: If you have a app that reads the NFC tag, that you get the location of the phone (e.g. GPS) and send that to the server. Another option migth be to write the specific location of each tag into the tag (if your customer can manage that).